# Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server

Tags: x11, xlib

What does the error "Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server" mean? The error is produced when an X client tries to call XvCreateImage(), and it results in the client terminating.

X.0.log shows the following version information:

```
X.Org X Server 1.6.4
Release Date: 2009-9-27
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Build Operating System: Linux 2.6.24-23-server i686 Ubuntu
Current Operating System: Linux ori-laptop 2.6.31-17-generic #54-Ubuntu SMP Thu Dec 10 16:20:31 UTC 2009 i686
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-2.6.31-17-generic root=UUID=df637de9-47ed-4453-9393-67e2e2ffaa2f ro quiet splas
```

Comment: I think we're going to need to know which X server and operating system we're talking about here.

Comment: I have the same problem. I am on Ubuntu 9.10.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem, i could solve it by removing `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome/peripherals`. You can move/rename the whole `~/.gconf/desktop/gnome` directory just to test if it works. Then just test folder by folder which one of the configurations causes the problem.

Hope it helps.