# See this example on webcam capturing in python

Tags: python, gstreamer

When I run this script on my machine ( ubuntu 10.04 32 bit ):

http://pygstdocs.berlios.de/pygst-tutorial/webcam-viewer.html

I click on "Start" button and then I get this error:

```
# python example-webcam.py 
example-webcam.py: Fatal IO error 0 (Success) on X server :0.0.
```

Why ?

Comment: Does this previous question help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2151937/fatal-io-error-0-success-on-x-server

Comment: When I run that app on my Ubuntu 10.10 64-bit install it just hangs when I click the start button.  I looked at the code for something obvious but nothing pops out.

Comment: Do you have the Video for Linux 2 (v4l2) drivers installed?

Comment: Because the example uses v4l2src so without v4l2 drivers it would not work.  However it's unlikely you don't have them.  Can you tell us why you think you don't?

Comment: Can you do this in a shell: gst-launch 'v4l2src ! autovideosink'   It would help determine if it's gst/drivers or Python/bindings.