# threading: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread

Tags: python, multithreading, qt, pyqt, qpixmap

I'm building a music player, that checks the status with SqueezePlay, which is a SqueezeBox controller app. To cut a long story short, I'm checking the status of Squeezeplay ever 5 seconds by using threading. If the song title changes, I let it update the labels (Qlabel, album artwork (QPixmap), etc. However, when I ask it to update it via threading, I'm getting **It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread** .

How can I do threading but still set the QPixmap?

Sample code:

```
#self.sq.getArtwork() returns variable with the image
coverArt = self.sq.getArtwork()
coverPixMap = QtGui.QPixmap()
coverPixMap.loadFromData(coverArt)
self.albumArt.setPixmap(coverPixMap)
```

Many thanks!

**Update:**
I tried the following with Emit, but it doesn't work, can someone take a look what I'm doing wrong?

```
def setNewArtwork(self, image):
    coverPixMap = QtGui.QPixmap()
    coverPixMap.convertFromImage(image)
    icon = QtGui.QIcon(coverPixMap)
    item.setIcon(icon)

def getNewArtwork(self):
    coverArt = self.sq.getArtwork()
    icon = QtGui.QImage(coverArt)
    self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('setNewArtwork(QImage)'), icon)
```

Comment: use QImage instead of QPixmap

Comment: `self.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('setNewArtwork(QImage)'), icon)` Should this line have QPixmap instead of QImage, since you're using pixmaps? I don't know how hard the types are enforced.

Also make sure that you're using a queued connection, if such a concept exist in PyQT. This ensures that the slot is run in the receiver's thread rather than the caller's thread.

Comment: When you say it "doesn't work" with signals, in what way doesn't it work? What goes wrong? The same thing? Something else?

Comment: @FLX: did you find a solution? I am interested.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All graphical Qt operations should happen in the main thread. Other threads are not really allowed to call Qt graphical operations (including probably pixmaps).

They could [emit Qt signals](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/signalsandslots.html) to the main thread. Or simply (on Linux) write into a pipe, and have the main [thread](http://qt-project.org/wiki/ThreadsEventsQObjects) wait for input on that pipe.

Of course, you have to define the signals (and also the slots) you want. In C++ code, you need to mark them with `signals:` (or `slots:`) and your C++ code should be processed by the [moc](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/moc.html#moc). I don't know what is the Python counterpart (perhaps python reflection abilities might be enough, I really don't know). You then have to connect signals to slots, with a *queued* connection. I have no idea how to do that in Python.

Comment: I'm kinda new to this, how would this be accomplished? I could really use some example code :)

Comment: I added some links. Qt documentation is much better than what I could explain in a few minutes!

Comment: Thanks Basile, I've tried it but it doesn't work; see my example in the original post - what am I doing stupidly wrong?

Comment: You probably have to define your signals and slots, and connect signals to slots. You should find out how to do that in Python (or code your application in C++, or with GTK...)

Answer (score 4):

To answer the question regarding how to emit the signal in python:

Unlike C++, when emitting a *user-defined* PyQt signal (as opposed to a Qt one), the signature should be omitted.

So, to emit the signal, do something like this:

```
thread.emit(QtCore.SIGNAL('newArtworkAvailable'), icon)
```

And to connect to the signal, do something like this:

```
widget.connect(thread, QtCore.SIGNAL('newArtworkAvailable'),
               widget.setNewArtwork)
```

And just to be clear:

For this to work, the non-gui thread must emit the signal, which is then received by the appropriate widget in the main gui thread. Creating a `QImage` in the non-gui thread should be okay, but never attempt to call any gui-related methods outside of the main thread.

**NB**:

I have used old-style signal syntax here because that is what you appear to be using. However, you might want to look at PyQt's [new-style signal and slot support](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/new_style_signals_slots.html) as it is much more flexible and pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

you probably need to send all your drawing jobs to the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

I've tried sth, please let me know if it rings a bell, i've done sth similar for mine (but im far from python for a while, so i may have made mistakes as well, if so, sorry.)

```
class MyThread(QThread, ui):
    def __init__(self, ui):
        super(MyThread, self).__init__(self)
        self.ui = ui

    def run(self):
       coverArt = self.ui.getArtwork()
       coverPixMap = QtGui.QPixmap()
       coverPixmap.convertFromImage(QtGui.QIcon(coverArt))
       icon = QtGui.QImage(coverPixMap)
       self.ui.item.setIcon(icon)  // set icon
       self.ui.singerLabel.setText("Singer")  // update label 

# your gui class
class YourInterface(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
       QtGui.QWidget.__init__(self)
        myThread = MyThread(self)
        self.myButton.clicked.connect(myThread.run)
        # all other stuff
        #
        #
```

Comment: This doesn't work. It would return something like: `QPixmap: It is not safe to use pixmaps outside the GUI thread`